# Full Bleed Design - Strategy

Tags: adobe-indesign, design-principles, book

I'm designing a book for a collection of 2d collage/design pieces. I'd like the images to come up to the trim line. I've read a lot about designing full bleed layouts and have experimented with InDesign and a template I acquired from Blurb that clearly outlines where the margin is, the trim, and where to take the image for full bleed. I'm pretty clear on how/why. What I'm not sure of is what are some strategies or principals for working with content that has already been designed (like these collage pieces) and in which the artist has frequently gone to the edge and where the edge is arguably an important compositional element. Maybe the answer is simply contain the image in a frame within the safe margin or take it to the edge and lose some of it in that .125" space. Maybe you have other ideas for finessing some middle ground.

Comment: Welcome! To be clear.. you're creating a book with full bleed art pieces on full bleed pages and the art is meant to cover the entire page of the book? So it's more an "art book" than anything else?

Comment: Woah -- somehow just seeing this comment months later. Yes, it was (is) an "art book" where I want to have art cover the entire page. The trick is that in some cases (actually many cases) there are important elements right at the edge of the original work. So the question becomes, how to go to the edge of the paper and maintain visibility of the original edge of the work too.

Answer (score 2):

A bleed must overlap the trim line, it doesn't just come up to the trim line. You will likely need to enlarge the image to make it overlap the edge. If the edge of the artwork is important compositionally, then a full bleed may not be suitable TBH.

You are always going to lose a bit of the artwork if it's set to bleed. There is no real way around this.

I think ultimately it's something you'd have to ask the original artist about. Will they mind if a few millimetres are cut off the border of their art?  Would it be possible/feasible for them to extend the artwork slightly over the edge?

If not, there are some possibilities I hesitate to mention, because they would really depend on the artwork, and possibly also depend on what the artist thinks about doing something like this ...

- You could slightly extend an artwork by using content aware fill in
  Photoshop, and perhaps clone parts of the image where it didn't quite
  work.
- You could leave the artwork as it is, but add a blurred enlarged copy
  underneath so you can bleed that off the edge. Will it look good
  though?  That's the problem.

Obviously the other option is not even to attempt this and ditch the idea entirely, and have the artwork inside the page bounds with a suitable white space all around.

Comment: Thank you. This confirms some of my thoughts. I'm going to break off a test book exploring a combination of options and see what happens. My guess is that some of the work will have to come to the safe margin and some can safely bleed without losing the composition.

Thanks again!